# Sending Mail through php Not working

Tags: php, smtp, sendmail

I have been trying to Make an email confirmation for my site. People can register with no problem, and everything registers into the database, but it does not send an email. I tried it normally, and it gave me some error about the smtp server, so someone said i should try SurgeMailer. I downloaded it, and now the emails actually say they sent, but the email never receives them. Any help would be great! Heres the code for sending the email.

```
/*Send Email here*/
$to=$Email;

$subject="Newgenstudios Account Confirmation";

/*From*/
$header="From:Newgenstudios <noreply@newgenstudios.com>";

/* Your message */   /*Not Finished */
$message = "<h3>Welcome to the site ".ucfirst(strtolower($First_Name))."!</h3>
<p>To complete your account registration, you must activate your account. Click on the link below or paste it into the URL to activate your account.</p>
<p><a href='http://localhost/confirmation.php?passkey=$confirm_code'>Activate Now!</a </p>
<p>Once your account has been activated, you may log in at anytime using the information you supplied below:<br />
<strong>Email: </strong>$Email<br />
<strong>Password: </strong>$Password</p>
<p>Other Information:</p>
<strong>Name: </strong>$First_Name<br />
<strong>Phone: </strong>$Phone<br />
<p>Thank you for registering and see you on the site!</p>
<p>Did you not register? Then please disregard this message.</p>";

/* Send Email */
$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
}

/*If not found*/
else {
echo "Not found your email in our database";
}

/* email succesfully sent */
if($sentmail){
echo "Your Confirmation link Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.";
}
else {
echo "Cannot send Confirmation link to your e-mail address";
}
?>
```

Comment: Check your log files for errors. The PHP `mail()` function doesn't guarantee the mail was sent, only that it was accepted for delivery.

Comment: btw in order to send HTML email you need to define the MIME-TYPE and Content-type. Example at bottom of page here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Comment: You don't have to include the MIME-TYPE and Content-Type.  It will send anyway.  

@user1868065 if it's your server check /var/log/maillog and see if there's any errors in there.  If you do not have access to the server, maybe try using SwiftMailer and using like IMAP to connect through another mail server.

Comment: you have not ended your anchor tag properly. first try to send hello as message it will work you have to add more headers to send hyperlink in your body

Answer (score 0):

1- try To use this mail function .

2- write " from value "  as valid email related to your domain, like : noreply@domain.com

3- if steps not work please call your hosting I guess mail() function blocked by them .

```
function send_mail($to,$from,$subject,$msg){
        // message
        $message = '
        <html>
        <head>
          <title>Message</title>
        </head>
        <body dir="rtl">
        <p align="right">'
        . $msg .
        '</p>
        <br>

        </p>
        </body>
        </html>
        ';

        // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\n";

        // Additional heade rs
        $headers .= "From: ".$from . "\n";
        //$headers .= 'Bcc: info@domain.co.uk' . "\n";

        // Mail it
        return mail($to, '=?windows-1256?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $headers);
    }
```

Comment: I actually just tried Php mailer, and it turns out also one of the php mail extensions were off, and tried it using the Phpmailer style, and it works out great, thanks for your help though too!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a Gmail account to send an email, that's the quickest one to set up for me. (just google 'send php gmail email'). And also, don't forget to check spam folder.